# Prove the center of $G$ cannot have order $p^{n-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime, let $n>2$ be an integer, and let $G$ be a nonabelian group of order $p^n$. Prove the center of G cannot have order $p^{n-1}$.

---

Honestly I have no idea where to start. Perhaps prove this by contradiction?

Comment: As a hint to Pedro's answer: for **any** group $\;G\;$ , the quotient $\;G/Z(G)\;$ cannot be cyclic non-trivial, or what ammounts to the same (why?): if $\;G/Z(G)\;$ is cyclic then $\;G\;$ is abelian. This can be expanded also to subgroups of the center but you don't need that for this problem.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: You don't understand...or you can't prove it?

Comment: Oh! I think I know. So if $Z(G)$ has order $p^{n-1}$, then the order of $G/Z(G)$ must be $p$, making $G/Z(G)$ cyclic which cannot happen since G is nonabelian. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5):

$G/Z(G)$ has order $p$; so it must be `______`? But if $G/Z(G)$ is `______` then it is trivial.

Comment: I'm confused. Wouldn't $Z(G)$ have order $p-1$ if $G/Z(G)$ has order $p$? I don't quite understand what you're saying

Comment: @allie What's the order of $G/H$ if you know the order of $G$ and the order of $H$?

Comment: So if Z(G) has order pn−1, then the order of G/Z(G) must be p, making G/Z(G) cyclic which cannot happen since G is nonabelian. Is this correct?

Comment: @allie That's correct.