# Let $G$ be a group of order $p^n$ where $p$ is prime. WITHOUT USING QUOTIENTS Prove that the center of $G$ cannot have order $p^{n-1}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^n$ where $p$ is prime.  Prove that the center  of $G$ cannot have order $p^{n-1}$ **without using quotients**.  The book I'm reading hasn't covered quotients or the meaning of the notation $A/B$ yet.

I tried by supposing the center is of order $p^{n-1}$, which implies there's $\phi(p^n)$ elements that aren't Abelian, but I'm not sure this is a good path.

Comment: If it does not make you feel bad, you may just rewrite the conclusion that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic without directly referencing quotients.

Comment: I haven't come across the notation $G/C$ or anything about quotients in my book yet.

Comment: In other words, you can rewrite [this duplicate proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762317/prove-the-center-of-g-cannot-have-order-pn-1?rq=1).

Comment: I don't understand how I'd rewrite it since the proof is based off of quotients.

Comment: You've suggested an approach by counting elements that do not commute with each other.  While the topic of quotients/group homomorphisms may not have been covered, apparently the notion of order of a subgroup/order of an element has.  Work with that.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a group with $Z(G)\ne G$ (in particular, $G$ is not abelian) and pick $a\in G\setminus Z(G)$.
Let $$A=\{\,a^kz\mid k\in\Bbb Z, z\in Z(G)\,\}.$$
Then $A$ is an abelian (hence proper) subgroup of $G$ because $a^kz\cdot a^{k'}z'=a^{k+k'}zz'$ and of course also a proper supergroup of $Z(G)$.
By multiplicativity of index, $$[G:Z(G)] =\underbrace{[G:A]}_{>1}\cdot \underbrace{[A:Z(G)]}_{>1}$$
cannot be prime.

If you do not have multiplacivity of index yet (or maybe not even index), you may just as well simply use that $|A|$ is a proper multiple of $|Z(G)|$ and a proper divisor of $|G|$. Or that $|A|=m\cdot |Z(G)|$ for some $m$ dividing the order of $a$, which again must divide $|G|$ - so that $m\ge p$.

Comment: How is $|A|$ a multiple of $|Z(G)|$ if $A$ is a proper subgroup of $Z(G)$?

Comment: $A$ is  a proper subgroup of $G$ not $Z(G)$.

Answer (score 1):

As Cave Johnson has said, you can just rewrite the proof pretending you don't know about quotients.

Let $Z(G)$ be of order $p^{n-1}$.

Take an element $a\not\in Z(G)$ and consider it's order. We know that $a$ has to have prime order by Lagrange. If $\{z_1,...,z_{p^{n-1}}\}=Z(G)$(distinct elements) we claim that $A_i=\{a^i z_1,...,a^i z_{p^{n-1}}\}$ for $i=1,...,p$ are pairwise disjoint and  are all of order $p^{n-1}$.

(Have you seen cosets? I presume you must have because you need it in the proof of Lagrange. In that case, the cosets $aZ(G),...,a^p Z(G)=Z(G)$ are pairwise disjoint and also all of size $p^{n-1}$. If you haven't the reason why they are pairwise disjoint is because if two elements $a^i z_m=a^j z_n$ then $a^{i-j}=z_n z_m^{-1})$ and if $i$ nad $j$ are distinct we can apply Bezout's theorem from number theory to invert $i-j$ to get an expression for $a$ in terms of elements in $Z(G)$)

We therefore have listed all the elements of $G$. Take two elements of $G$ and we see htat

$a^i z_m a^j z_n=a^i a^jz_m z_n =a^j a^i z_n z_m=a^j z_n a^i z_m$

(Try and justify to yourself why each of these parts commuted.)

Comment: I don't understand what the contradiction to $Z(G)$ being of order $p^{n-1}$ is here.

Comment: Yes, abelian implies $|Z(G)|=p^{n}$ but we have shown that $|Z(G)|=p^{n-1}$ implies abelian. It's not quite a proof by contradiction. We just ended up showing that all the elements commute.

Comment: What are you indexing in $A_i = az_1, ..., az_{pn-1}$?

Comment: But what in the set is being indexed?  Otherwise $A_1 = \{az_1, ..., az_{pn-1}\} = A_2 = \{az_1, ..., az_{pn-1}\}, ...$ ?

Comment: Powers of $a$. I've just made the correction

Comment: But how can you be sure that the powers of $a$ aren't in $Z(G)$?  Because couldn't $a \notin G$ have an order of $p^k$ which isn't prime because for $k < n$, $p^k | p^n$?

Comment: I just need $p$ distinct "cosets". If $a^i=z$ for $i<p$ then we can invert the power since $a$ has $p$-power order by elementary number theory.(Bezout's Theorem, Euclid's algorithm because  $p$ and $i$ are coprime). In other words, there exists $j$ such that $a^{ij}=a=z^j$ which contradicts our initial assumption that $a$ is not in $Z(G)$. (Z(G) is a subgroup.) I don't even need that $a^p$ is the identity element because it need not be.

Comment: I don't understand how that shows that it won't be the case that the powers of $a$ aren't in $Z(G)$, what if no power of $a$ is in $Z(G)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43262/discussion-between-daruma-and-oliver-g).